# Ubuntu emulator won't boot up on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: ubuntu-emulator, systemd-logind

I created an Ubuntu emulator using the device creator in the Ubuntu-SDK using the i386 architecture, stable and default password. When I try to run it using the terminal I get the usual output as it boots up the emulator and then I get this:

```
mount: mounting /dev/mtdblock2 on /root/android//cache failed: Invalid argument
[    3.121581] initrd: mounting /root/var/lib/lxc/android/system.img as /root/android/system
Begin: Running /scripts/local-bottom ... done.
done.
Begin: Running /scripts/init-bottom ... done.
[    4.162575] init: ureadahead-touch main process (291) terminated with status 5
[    5.822531] init: no-cpu-hotplug main process (458) terminated with status 1
[    7.941528] init: /dev/hw_random not found
[    7.941528] init: cannot open '/initlogo.rle'
[    8.007849] init: /dev/hw_random not found
[    8.131365] init: cannot find '/system/etc/install-recovery.sh', disabling 'flash_recovery'
[    8.131365] init: cannot find '/system/bin/ubuntuappmanager.disabled', disabling 'ubuntuappmanager'
[    8.211827] init: property 'sys.powerctl' doesn't exist while expanding '${sys.powerctl}'
[    8.211827] init: powerctl: cannot expand '${sys.powerctl}'
[    8.211827] init: property 'sys.sysctl.extra_free_kbytes' doesn't exist while expanding '${sys.sysctl.extra_free_kbytes}'
[    8.211827] init: cannot expand '${sys.sysctl.extra_free_kbytes}' while writing to '/proc/sys/vm/extra_free_kbytes'
[    8.211827] init: cannot find '/sbin/adbd', disabling 'adbd'
 * Setting up X socket directories...                                    [ OK ] 
[   26.181740] systemd-logind[772]: Failed to start unit user@32011.service: Unknown unit: user@32011.service
[   26.181740] systemd-logind[772]: Failed to start user service: Unknown unit: user@32011.service
[   26.631759] systemd-logind[772]: Failed to start unit user@0.service: Unknown unit: user@0.service
[   26.631759] systemd-logind[772]: Failed to start user service: Unknown unit: user@0.service
```

So the emulator never boots up. I only get the emulator window.

*Does anyone knows how to fix this?*